# Hopeful Monsters in Plants?

Tags: botany, theoretical-biology

Does anyone know of any research/examples on Hopeful Monsters in Plants?

I define Hopeful Monsters as organisms of a species that have macroevolutions to prompt new speciations. These macroevolutions being themselves, prompted by smaller gradual microevolutions in the species. See [this](http://www.evolocus.com/publications/Theissen2006.pdf) paper for more details. I'm interested in a plant based example, or any good recent example, if plants can not suffice. Ideally research that is easily read and recent, and useful for arguing the existence of themselves?

Comment: Could you please add more context to your question? I'm not particularly familiar with the term Hopeful Monsters.

Comment: I found a review on the topic for those who are also not familiar of the different versions of evolution theories: http://www.evolocus.com/publications/Theissen2006.pdf

Comment: @poka.nandor       I define Hopeful Monsters as organisms of a species that have macroevolutions to prompt new speciations. These macroevolutions being themselves, prompted by smaller gradual microevolutions in the species. I want a plant based example, or any good recent example, if plants can not suffice.

Comment: I didn't the term "Hypoeful Monsters" before. From [Wiki](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Hopeful_monster), the term "hopefull monsters" designate a concept (a hypothesis) and not an organism. In the same logic, the term "macroevolution" has a meaning that depends only on the observer and not on the underlying evolutionary processes. It means "evolution observed at a scale of separated gene pool". In any case, the term "macroevolution(s)" as a noun don't have any meaning to my knowledge. What do you mean by "macroevolutions"? Also, what do you mean by "microevolutions"?

Comment: I've edited these extra info along with the paper I found into your question, so it has all these details and don't get lost in comment section. You can roll back at any time if you wish.

Comment: Is your question "Can you give examples of plant lineages that underwent major mutations (such as chromosomal rearrangement or hybridization or change in ploidy level)?" or maybe it is something like "Can you give examples of plant lineages which fundamental niche has suddenly and drastically changed in response to a single (or few) mutations?" or stated differently is would be "Do you know examples in plants lineages of mutations that had a major impact on the ecology occupied by the species?"

Comment: What do you mean with a species having "*macroevolutions*" that are "*prompted by smaller gradual microevolutions*"? This doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @fileunderwater   Sorry, I am not too great with biology( im a stupid undergrad). Can a species have macroevolution happen to it? Am i phrasing it wrong? If a species can have macroevolution happen to it, can then this macroevolution be caused by microevolution(small, gradual, changes in  allele freq in a population).

Comment: @RoSiv Macroevolution is mostly a label describing a level of studying evolution (macroevolution ~= evolution above the species level), and not a type of evolutionary change. Most evolutionary biologists would find it rather meaningless to talk about macroevolutionary changes "happening" to  a species. Macroevolution is the accumulated  result of many small evolutionary changes (i.e. microevolutionary changes). So in that sense, macroevolution is caused by microevolution. Sure, some  single mutations can have larger effects than others, but this is not macroevolution.

Comment: @fileunderwater   Can I ask you then how you would define and relate the four terms, Hopeful Monsters, Macroevolution, Microevolution, and polyploidy? So that I can get a solidified view on this, because to be honest I have some confusion with the concepts now. Thank you.

Comment: @RoSiv A starting point for the relationship macroevolution and microevolution (or simply just *evolution*) can be found in my previous comment. I hadn't heard about "*Hopeful monsters*" before, so I cannot really say anything about that. Polyploidization is a full genome duplication (polyploidy is just the state of having more than two homologous chromosomes), a common cause of speciation in plants and a good example of a single event that can have large evolutionary consequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your question is but here is an example that may interest you.

- The three sunflower species *Helianthus anomalus*, *H. deserticola*, and *H. paradoxus* are all of hybrid origin of the same two "parent species" (*H. annuus* and *H. petiolaris*).

[Major ecological transitions in wild sunflowers facilitated by hybridization](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12907807) is a paper that will likely interest you. This paper has been written by L. Riesberg and colleagues. You may want to read through some of the work of L. Rieseberg (CactusWoman already linked one of his articles).

Answer (score 2):

One example of what you may consider to be a macroevolutionary change is a whole-genome-duplication, or polyploidy event. These are not uncommon in plants, and can promote speciation due to a reproductive barrier arising between the polyploid progeny and the diploid parents. You can find many papers about this topic, here is one from 2009: http://www.pnas.org/content/106/33/13875.short